# ASP.net Identity System empty project using vb

Tags: asp.net, identity

i want to ask if there are references on how to implement identity on an existing website using vb.
all articles and blogs in ASP.net/learn use C#
I have installed packages. Is transferring C# classes to vb classes will be solution? please direct me.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: thanks confile. about Creating Custom DbContext, User and Role classes using vb language and owin startup class, usermanager and rolemanager and accountcontroller classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to create a new website using vb and forms template and replace it by adding the existing website and modifying its design structure like home page and master pages and replacing styles and scripts. This is some long solution but it is remain easier and more efficient than others.